# How do I show this in flowchart?

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

I have two 4-digit arrays, both arrays consist of different numbers in themselves, like Array1:1234, Array2: 4567.
Firstly, I should check if any digit of these two arrays are the same
Secondly, if there is a same digit, I should check if there are any other same digits apart from last one.

How do I show this in flowchart?

Comment: You have to make an attempt first, and show what you have thought about as your algorithm to meet the use case you described. When you write "check if any digit", you mean to check the number ( which may be 4 digit number).

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I think he has `type Arr = array of char [4]` and actually talks about the digits.

Comment: Well he hasn't even told anything about the language he intends to implement in.  May be he meant the digits. Basically it is intersection set of those 2 arrays that he is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is what a flowchart would look like using ASCII art. You may wish to use a graphical program to create a prettier picture.

```
  .--------+  .--------+
 / Array1 /  / Array2 /
+--------'  +--------'
     |           |
     +---->+<----+
           |
           v
          / \
         /   \      +--------------+
        /     \  No | Find numbers |   .------.
       + Same? +----> common to    |->(  Done. )
        \     /     | both arrays. |   `------'
         \   /      +--------------+
          \ /
           +
           | Yes
     .-----v-----.
    (    Done.    )
     `-----------'
```

To represent the actual algorithm, the flow chart allows iteration by drawing a line to loop onto an earlier component in the diagram. You would use a decision box to test if the loop invariant is true and or test the stopping condition. The decision box would then either continue the loop or move to a different path of logic.

For example, to check if an array has the number 0:

```
  .-------+
 / Array /
+-------'
    |
+---v-------+
| Start at  |
| beginning |
| of array  |
+-----------+
    |        +-----------------+
    +<-------| Increment index |<---------------+
    |        +-----------------+                |
    v                                  +        |
   / \                                / \       |
  /   \      +------------------+    /   \      |
 / At  \  No | Compare number   |   /     \  No |
+  end? +----> at current array |--> Same? +----+
 \     /     | index with 0.    |   \     /
  \   /      +------------------+    \   /
   \ /                                \ /
    +                                  +
    | Yes                              | Yes
 .--v-------.                       .--v---.
( Not found. )                     ( Found. )
 `----------'                       `------'
```

Comment: The good thing about flowcharts and the question is, that it leaves the wanted level of abstraction open to interpretation :) So, a simple 1 box thing would do just as well: `(a1,a2) -> (Common Number Task) -> (common-digits)`

Comment: If you sort both arrays first, you get a more efficient (runtime) solution. Then, you can iterate both arrays a1,a2 with 2 indices i,j and depending on the digits relation, you can increment i (a1[i] < a2[i]), j (a2[j] < a1[i]), i and j (a1[i] == a2[j]).

Comment: @BitTickler I am taking the question to mean how to translate an algorithm into a flow chart, rather than a question about how come up with an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This question touches a sensitive area of software development in general.

One school of thought pretends, it is beneficial to first plan out thoroughly before implementing something.

The other school of thought does not agree. They usually prefer "rapid prototyping" over painting flow charts. And with some very good and valid reasons:

1. Every step in software development needs a verification step (quality gate principle). How do you verify a flowchart for being correct?
2. Someone just invented a new programming language, the flowchart language. Just because it is graphical, it does not avoid the typical problems of programming languages: Hard to proof correctness, while execution (testing) often creates sufficient trust in the solution.

So, as for the question, since I am rather of camp (2), not so much of camp (1), my advice is: Implement your idea first, and then if someone absolutely wants it, create the flowchart from your solution. Or even better use a tool, which transforms your implementation into a flowchart (avoids transcription bugs).